# Creating a table with the vectors filling the rows

Tags: r

I have 4 separate vectors:

```
m1=c(83,92,92,46,67)
m2=c(117,109,114,104,87)
m3=c(101,93,92,86,67)
m4=c(105,119,116,102,116)
```

Now I want to combine these vectors into 1 table so that m1 fills in the first row, m2 fills the second and so on. So I used the `cbind` function and created this and got the following result:

cbind(m1,m2,m3,m4)

```
     m1  m2  m3  m4
[1,] 83 117 101 105
[2,] 92 109  93 119
[3,] 92 114  92 116
[4,] 46 104  86 102
[5,] 67  87  67 116
```

which is not what I wanted because the individual vectors fill in the columns. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try `rbind()` ?

Comment: Or transpose the result with `t()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three easy ways (perhaps more):

```r
rbind(m1,m2,m3,m4)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# m1   83   92   92   46   67
# m2  117  109  114  104   87
# m3  101   93   92   86   67
# m4  105  119  116  102  116
t(cbind(m1,m2,m3,m4))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# m1   83   92   92   46   67
# m2  117  109  114  104   87
# m3  101   93   92   86   67
# m4  105  119  116  102  116
matrix(c(m1,m2,m3,m4), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   83   92   92   46   67
# [2,]  117  109  114  104   87
# [3,]  101   93   92   86   67
# [4,]  105  119  116  102  116
```